# How can i convert base64 encoded file to normal.jpg file?

Tags: python, base64, decode, encode

Hi this is my example base64 encoded file :

```
myencodeimage = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
```

i wanna make jason.jpg this encoded text.

```
g = open("out.jpg", "w")
g.write(base64.decodestring(myencodeimage))
g.close()
```

But i have a "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding" problem ?

Comment: the first problem I see: the original image is png, not JPEG. The second problem is that what you want to decode in base64 is the part of the string after the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to decode the whole string, instead of only the base64 encoded data.

```
myencodeimage = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
```

try to decode

```
myencodeimage = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
```

But keep in mind that the image is in a PNG container and not a compressed JPEG image, so basically your OS won't be able to call the correct program to open the image in the worst case.